# Connect to second database in another MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, bluehost, mysql-connect

I have a system in Bluehost which I could connect easily to the database with

```
$con = new_mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
```

But I'm also trying to establish a second connection, but not in the Bluehost, but in a local server we have. So we created an outside IP for it so we can access the MySQL database that it has.

I try to connect it with this:

```
$con2 = new_mysqli("XXX.XX.XXX.XX", "root", "", "database");
```

But it only returns this error.

> Connect failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XX.XXX.XX' (110)

Why am I not connecting? Is there a configuration that I miss out?

You can comment for further details that I might have missed.

Comment: this is because your outside IP (server/host) is not open for remote access I think